# read outlook msg files with node js

Tags: node.js, outlook, msg

I'm trying to read msg-files that are exported from outlook.

Is there a way of reading the original recipient in the msg-file 
with nodejs? (I don't have online office365, I'm talking about files on disk).

As a rare exception, I couldn't find a npm module for this :-)

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Can you provide any documentation or examples of what msg files exported from Outlook look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this library to be very useful - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kenjiuno/msgreader

Ideally, you'd be doing something like this:

```
import MsgReader from '@kenjiuno/msgreader';
import * as fs from 'fs'

readMail = () => { 
var readFileAsBuffer = fs.readFileSync('fileLocationHere');
var msgReader = new MSGReader(readFileAsBuffer );
var fileData = msgReader.getFileData();
//FileData will have body, subject etc
var getBody = fileData.body;
}
```